# Not sure if a question about release dates is appropriate for the site

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I want to ask the question "why are games released in different countries on different days, even when the digital download is available?"

But I'm not sure if this falls under the "ask the devs" category. So I'm asking here if the question appropriate?

Comment: I'd imagine the answer might often be, "because the non-digital copy isn't available yet", and because publishers have a vested interest in keeping brick & mortar stores on the same start date as digital ones.

Comment: stupid brick and mortar stores, making me wait 3 more days for AC III.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to go with "probably not" for a couple of reasons:

One is, as you note, that it's a decision made by developers/publishers, so any answer we give is likely to be speculative.

Second is that it's broad - the answer might vary depending on the game.

The second could probably be fixed, but then you're still left with the first.  Overall, I'd expect it to get closed quickly.